# Import column from Oracle to Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

Can what I asked in my title be done?

I would ultimately like to compare a value in Python to all the values in a column in my Oracle table, so I've attempted the following:

```
select_statement = ("SELECT STOCK_ID FROM FISHTABLE")
cursor.execute(select_statement)

new_IDList = (''.join(IDList))
if new_IDList in "STOCK_ID":
    print("it's there")
else:
    print("it's not there")
```

but obviously that won't work because the entire column isn't within the string `'STOCK_ID'`.

I have a value, a string, called `new_IDList` and its value changes each time I run my code; it parses out an ID from the table I run it on. I want to see "if that value occurs in the Oracle table, then do blah blah blah, if not, do something else".

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How about adding a `WHERE` clause, so Oracle does the work?

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of a beginner with SQL. Where would I add the `WHERE` clause and what exactly what that do?

Comment: @theprowler  I think you need to do a little basic research on the SQL SELECT statement.